How can I replicate a curl -u in a header?
With a curl command I execute:
curl -u appId:secret https://api.example.com

This works I then attempt to do it with headers like so:
{
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "`Bearer appId`"
}

401 error I then attempt:
{
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "Bearer appId+secret"
}
401, any idea how I would do this?
••• The purpose is that I need to do something similar in a no code software which is asking me to set the header.  So I won't be using curl.
